# Wordpress search strange behaviour

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, forms, search

Has anyone come across or have a fix for the following Wordpress search issue:

When you search '***degrees***', you get results.

If you search '***degree***', you get no results.

Very strange!

Live site demo here:
http://advice.milkround.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all if you are not using any search plugin, the default wp search would search all posts and pages for the reference degree. If you declared a custom post type where you have the search term "degree", then wordpress would not search trough the custom post types.

Try installing one of the wp search plugins and configure it to work with cpt and try again.